# Windows 10 Printing doesn't work globally

Tags: drivers, pdf, printing, printer

I recently did a windows reset, as there were many unused software cluttering the performance. However, after that, I'm unable to perform any kind of printing operation. This includes

- Printing word docs or excel sheets to pdfs (Microsoft Print to PDF) (Below is a sample error message)
- Physically printing onto paper (The printer, in this case, is set up well and works with other computers)
- Other options like print to OneNote etc

[image: Sample Error]

**What have I tried?**

- Printer troubleshooting - didn't detect any errors, and recommended that I set one of the options to default, which also didn't help
- Reinstalled the 'Print to PDF' drivers
- Tried a few other online fixes

none of which worked. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem after windows reset. After every restart, the status of all printers including Microsoft  print to pdf and print to onenote for windows 10 is shown as " not connected". I couldn't solve the problem. But, a work around to get the printers connected is as follows.  This is to be done after every restart.

1. Start onenote for windows 10.
2. Print something from one note.
3. All the printers will now be connected.

If you don't want to waste paper, select print to PDF as printer and cancel the print after the dialogue box for saving the file is open. Cancel both save dialogue as well as print job.

I have no clue as to why it is happening but it has got something to do with driver for " print to onenote for windows 10" printer.

Comment: A strange bug indeed! But this workaround does solve the purpose!

Comment: If anybody can give an explanation or a permanent solution, I will be happy.